# Cannot build STXXL with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stxxl

It seems that I cannot build the solution for STXXL with CMake 2.8.12.1. I looked at all the articles and followed their instructions but no luck. I have VS2010 Professional with SP1 and Windows 7. I select Visual Studio 10 Win64 in CMake and click configure but I always get the following:

```
The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

I have ticked the `Run As Administrator` checkbox for `cl.exe` but still nothing.

Does anyone know how I can build STXXL? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

After installing VS2012 I managed to use CMake successfully and generate the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of STXXL, (nor I think of CMake), but of VS2010's support for 64-bit compilation.

I remember testing STXXL with the 32-bit compilers of VS2010, and it worked fine. Use 32-bit (which is kind of out of fashion) or upgrade. Upgrading is the easiest road to go.